# Problems in trying to create a hotspot in RPI3

Tags: pi-3, hotspot

I am relatively new to Raspberry Pi programming, and have been using a RPi3 to try and create a hotspot in order to send data from an Android device using MQTT.

I use `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` in order to create the hotspot and have tried using two different methods for the IP address.

Using a static IP address, I am able to create the hotspot and connect to it. However, the MQTT connection fails, and I am not able to send data from the Android.

Using a manual IP address, I am able to create a hotspot but not connect it. Trying to connect to it shows the device trying to obtain the IP address indefinitely. Additionally, hovering over the Wi-Fi symbol on the Raspbian Desktop shows the message:

> Connection to dhcpcd lost.

I tried following all the basic tutorials and guides, involving `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`, modified the `dnsmasq.conf` file, `network/interfaces` file and such. However, the same problem seems to arise, being:

> Connection to dhcpcd lost.

This is what I have done so far,

Modified the `hostapd.conf` file as follows

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPIHotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=123456789
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

The `dnsmasq.conf` as follows

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

and changed the `network/interfaces` as

```
auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
# wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The `dhcpcd.conf` file

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.42
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
interface=wlan0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.1.8,192.168.1.250,12h`
```

After doing so, I restarted the `hostapd`, and `dnsmasq` files. And after rebooting the system, dhcpcd was lost

Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I tried following all the basic tutorials and guides" - including all the obsolete guides?

Comment: @Milliways I don't think so, I've used the recent ones I think, like the one on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md, but they still don't work.

Comment: My point was you haven't told us what **YOU DID** or why you think it doesn't work

Comment: @Milliways I've added what I have done. Hope this helps

Comment: In other words you did not follow the tutorial you linked!

Comment: @Milliways, this is what is given in the tutorial. I've followed the tutorial word for word. And what I did in my Pi, I have posted here.

Comment: I see no mention of `iface wlan0 inet manual` in `interfaces` which mentions `# Bridge setup` and you have not mentioned the changes to `dhcpcd`

Comment: @Milliways, I added the changes to dhcpcd, and I don't need the hotspot to access the internet, just for data transfer. If I'm not mistakes, isn't the bridge used for enabling the hotspot to access the internet?